# Existence of $x \in E$ such that $\sup(E)-\epsilon<x\le \sup(E)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\alpha=\sup\left(E\right)$ exists, I often encounter the argument
that there exists a point $x\in E$  such that

$\sup\left(E\right)-\epsilon<x\leq\sup\left(E\right)$

I realize that if $\sup\left(E\right)\in E$, then I can just chose
$x=\sup\left(E\right)$ and the argument would be valid.

But what if $\sup\left(E\right)\notin E$? Is it then true that, there exists
a point $x\in E$ such that

$\sup\left(E\right)-\epsilon<x<\sup\left(E\right)$

?

Related to the question: Are the following two statements correct?

$\alpha=\sup\left(E\right)\in E\implies\alpha\text{ can be either an isolated point or a limit point of }E$

$\alpha=\sup\left(E\right)\notin E\implies\alpha\text{ can only be a limit point of }E$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose no such $x$ existed. Would this be consistent with the definition of $\sup(E)$ as the *least* upper bound?

---

And indeed, your assessment of the limit point/isolated point properties of $\sup(E)$ is correct.

Comment: If no such $x$ existed, $\sup\left(E\right)$ cannot be a supremum (because $\sup\left(E\right)-\epsilon$ would be an upper bound and smaller than $\sup\left(E\right)$). Thanks for pointing out.